# Obtener el valor de un table

Tags: javascript, jsp

Buen día quiero obtener un valor de esta tabla al momento de hacer clic:

```
<table>
<th>2016</th>
<th>2017</th>
<th>2018</th>
<th>2019</th>
<th>2020</th>
</table>
```

Con esta función :

```
$("table").click(function(){
    alert($(this).find("th").eq(1).html());
    });
```

No me funciona espero alguien pueda indicarme que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: ¿El valor de una tabla, es decir todo el contenido ? ¿ O una Fila en particular ? ¿ O una columna en particular?

Comment: Lo siento formule mal mi pregunta ya realice la corrección, un ejemplo si hago clic en el 2017 me tome ese valor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El siguiente código te va a alertar el valor del elemento clickeado:

```js
$("table th").click(function(){
  alert($(this).html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <th>2016</th>
  <th>2017</th>
  <th>2018</th>
  <th>2019</th>
  <th>2020</th>
</table>
```

Si haces click en la tabla, y quieres que te regrese solo el primer valor, tu función de JavaScript puede ser de esta manera, utilizando :first-child

```js
$("table").click(function(){
  alert($("table th:first-child").html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <th>2016</th>
  <th>2017</th>
  <th>2018</th>
  <th>2019</th>
  <th>2020</th>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Tienes que iterar por todos los 'th' de tu table, por cada uno de ellos, tomás el valor:

```
var thCount = $('table th').length;
$("table").click(function(){
for(var i = 0; i< thCount; i++){
alert($(this).find("th").eq(i).html());
}});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
<th>2016</th>
<th>2017</th>
<th>2018</th>
<th>2019</th>
<th>2020</th>
</table>
<script>
var thCount = $('table th').length;
$("table").click(function(){
for(var i = 0; i< thCount; i++){
alert($(this).find("th").eq(i).html());
}
    
    });
</script>
```